# App submission failed due to icon dimensions (0 x 0)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.2

I am trying to submit an app which is only for iPhone.

The error showed " iPhone/iPod Touch: Icon.png: icon dimensions (0 x 0) don't meet the size requirement. The icon file must be 57x57 pixels, in .png format.

May I know why this happens? I try to change the plist setting and i am sure my icon is at the right size. It shows perfectly on my iPhones.

I have searched for few post here but still cannot find the solution.

Could anyone knows the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 58, accepted):

According to this solution https://devforums.apple.com/message/612098#612098 make this steps:

1. Install [ApplicationLoader_2.5.1.dmg](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/apploader/ApplicationLoader_2.5.1.dmg) (Just install it, you don't need to launch/use it)
2. Quit & restart Xcode
3. Clean Project
4. Archive (again)
5. Validate/Submit now works

This solution fixed my problems with submission.

Comment: Apple's Dev Tools quality is getting worse. Xcode is one big mem hog -  4.2.1 on 10.7.3 non-SSD 4GB OS is slower then snail mail ;)

Comment: I couldn't believe that this would actually work cos I thought the Application Loader was built into Xcode, and since I hade the latest Xcode it should have all worked. BUT it did work! YAY!

Comment: @DonnaLea - probably XCode and Application Loader using this same library (libraries) which was changed in 10.7.3. Reinstalling of Applications Loader brings back correct version of this libraries.

Comment: Since this topic is still not closed i have a chance to say THANK YOU! :D

Comment: Just remember to launch Application Loader for the first time to accept the terms, otherwise you will get a different error

Comment: I am having this very problem on SL 10.6.8, Xcode 4.2 (4C199). The funny thing is, the same project built/submitted without issues a couple of weeks ago. I can not re-submit the SAME binary (the one that uploaded without problems), because of validation error, nor build a new one (build warning + validation error)

Comment: This worked for me. For those looking for Application Loader, to launch it once (as per @Daniel's suggestion), search in finder for 'Loader'. ('Application Loader' didn't give me any results, for some reason). In any case, it seems to be installed in /Applications/Utilities/

Answer (score 39):

Tomasz's solution is fine, but there's a much simpler solution: select your Icon.png and Icon@2x.png, and in the right-hand side inspector, change File Type from "PNG" to "Icon".

[image]

After this change, you can Archive and submit your application as you normally would directly within XCode.

Comment: This worked for me on Lion 10.7.3 and Xcode 4.2.1, thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly. This should be the verified answer. The other feels like a hack.

Comment: This is one of the more cleaner answers here. Cheers Andrew! +1

Comment: How to make this work on Snow Leopard? There's no "File Type" option when I click "Get Info". :(

Comment: +1 because I didn't know this trick. Tomasz's solution did it for me too. But, can you use this trick with Vertex/Fragment shaders? (OpenGL ES 2.0) Xcode treats them as 'source files' by default, even though they should be treated as 'resources' (bundled as text files and compiled at run time by the GL driver)

Comment: @Joel & Praveen S: agree, and I heavily doubt that .dmg works on earlier versions of the OS. BlackBook: In top right corner, enable rich hand column. Select the file in left column and the little document icon above the new right column.

Comment: Works like a charm. Straight and great answer!! Thanks Andrew.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have (at minimum) a 57x57px icon and a 114x114px icon. Typically these will be called Icon.png and Icon@2x.png.

Then in your info.plist, there is an array called 'Icon files'. You need to add both image names to that array.

Comment: I use `icon_57.png`, `icon_114.png`, `icon_72.png`, `icon_144.png`. But I could use `icon.png`, `icon@2x.png`, `icon~ipad.png` and `icon~ipad@2x.png` as well. Having the size explicit in the name makes it less confusing for the graphic designer. I assume that as long as the names match those in the `info.plist`, there should be no problem.

Comment: I think it's better to get designers familiar with the @2x naming convention becomes it comes up a lot. For iPads you should use Icon-72.png and Icon-72@2x.png for iPad3 - Apple actually have explicit guidelines for the names here (although they've not been updated for iPad3): http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html

Comment: As you say, as long as the names match the plist you can use whatever names you want, but generally if Apple already have a convention it's probably best to use it.

Comment: I agree it's wisest NOT to get at odds with the OS regarding resource name qualifiers such as "@2x".

Answer (score 0):

Have to try to Clean & Rebuild ? in xCode, try to right click on the App Icon > choose "Delete", then re-pick the Icon.

Make sure it is PNG , non-interlaced.