# icon dimensions don't meet the size requirements (0x0)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, submission

icon dimensions don't meet the size requirements (0x0)

I got this error when submitting an app to appstore today.
I tracked it down to the fact that the icons are getting "png-crushed", many people have solved this by disabling compressPNG's in the application build settings, however png-crush does a lot more than just compress, it also optimise's (which I want to keep!)

So I found that my icons were in a subfolder (not called resources) and not in the root.

Simply moving them to the root and updating the project with the new path(s) solved the problem without having to turn off png compressing for everything!

Comment: Hear, hear. So, uhm, what's the question? :)

Comment: Full error was ... iPhone/iPod Touch: Icon.png: icon dimensions (0 x 0) don't meet the size requirements. The icon file must be 57x57 pixels, in .png format

Comment: I answered my own question sorry, I'm a noob to asking questions here!

Comment: I had the similar problem, answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9174514/app-submission-failed-due-to-icon-dimensions-0-x-0 helped me. Please do some searching before you post duplicates.

Comment: Suggest: Edit your question into the form of a question.  Then put the answer in the form of an answer.  This will help others with similar problems be better able to read this page.

Comment: -1 stackoverflow will stay usable with correct titles and no duplicates. Thanks for your comprehension,

Answer (score 9):

Edit Project Settings -> Build -> uncheck Compress PNG Files，and everything be OK.

Answer (score 4):

May be [this](https://devforums.apple.com/message/612098#612098) would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I encoutered this error and resolved it using coolercat's project settings. Surprisingly, I did NOT get this last month when I submitted the same project compiled for a differently branded app target (with different app id, apple account, and icons).