# Xcode - archiving an app - icon issues

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4.2, archiving

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [App submission failed due to icon dimensions (0 x 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9174514/app-submission-failed-due-to-icon-dimensions-0-x-0)

I am about to submit my app but when trying to archive, xcode keep telling me that the icon has (0x0) dimensions and need to be (57x57). I have double checked that it is 57x57 but still xcode sees it as 0x0

```
warning: iPhone/iPod Touch: iconNormal.png: icon dimensions (0 x 0) don't meet the size requirements.  The icon file must be 57x57 pixels, in .png format (-19014)
```

Unable to validate your application. - (null)

Comment: -1 stackoverflow will stay usable with correct titles and no duplicates. Thanks for your comprehension,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have updated to OS X 10.7.3,
Updating the Application Loader will fix the issue.

Download here:
https://itunesconnect.apple.com/apploader/ApplicationLoader_2.5.1.dmg

Also see [App submission failed due to icon dimensions (0 x 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9174514/app-submission-failed-due-to-icon-dimensions-0-x-0/9174614#9174614)

Answer (score 0):

Delete the file and then re-add it to the project.  It looks like it exists, but it's corrupt or lacking data.  Also, make sure the PNG is coming from a valid editor - which image editor are you using?

Comment: Sorry, but this is well known error after updating Lion to 10.7.3 - here is solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9174514/app-submission-failed-due-to-icon-dimensions-0-x-0/9174614#9174614

Comment: Well, good thing I'm lazy about updating.  Thanks Tomasz.