# Error with icon files in xcode 4.2

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I have just updated to osx 10.73 and updated xcode 4.2. I'm now getting an error on validate in xcode; it's saying that my icons are the wrong size (when they are not) and it's giving me a warning that my launch images for ipad are the wrong size (when they are not). I have had my designer re-check the images, and I have re-checked the images, and I'm still getting this error.

Has anyone else got this error? I'm not too sure whether this is a code issue? All help is appreciated as I was going to submit my app today.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing [ApplicationLoader_2.5.1.dmg](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/apploader/ApplicationLoader_2.5.1.dmg).

I had similiar problem, got the idea from [App submission failed due to icon dimensions (0 x 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9174514/app-submission-failed-due-to-icon-dimensions-0-x-0) and it helped.

Comment: I fixed it by turning off compress png images in complier settings and i stopped getting error I dont know why it started as that setting was always on but it worked thank you for answer