# Icon error after running app on an iPod touch 4g with IOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios5, icons, ipod

I have an app on the App Store and I want to update it. But after I ran/tested my app on a iPod touch I keep getting this error message when I run it on the iPhone and on the iPod, but not on simulator (on the simulator I get no issues):

warning: iPhone/iPod Touch: TGDM114.png: icon dimensions (0 x 0) don't meet the size requirements.  The icon file must be 57x57 pixels, in .png format (-19014)
Unable to validate your application. - (null)

I have always had two icons, one 57*57 and one 114*114. The app is built for iPhone and I used storyboard. I thought it would be no problem running on a 4g iPod touch that has IOS5 but I guess I was wrong.

My questions are:

Can't I use my iPod for developing?

and:

Can I somehow change back to my settings before I tested it on the iPad so I can update my app?

Thanks on beforehand!

Answer (score 0):

This is common problem when upgrading to OS 10.7.3.

Dont't ask why but upgrading ApplicationLoader to ApplicationLoader_2.5.1.dmg
seems to help :)

Check accepted answer here, it helped me and lots of others:

[App submission failed due to icon dimensions (0 x 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9174514/app-submission-failed-due-to-icon-dimensions-0-x-0)

Comment: Thanks a lot Rokjarc! Now it's uploaded. Sorry stackoverflow for missing that this question already had an answer.