# Xcode Project Icon files issue

Tags: iphone

on submitting the app to the app store I get the following issue. But the size of the icon in the folder is showing 57x57 dimension.

> iPhone/iPad Touch: icon.png: icon dimensions (0x0) don’t meet the size requirements. The icon file must be 57x57 pixels, in .png format

I am using xcode 3.2.5 for the project

Comment: Please check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9421680/662096

Comment: As of May 1 you can't submit apps that are not build with the iOS6 SDK, since you are using Xcode 3.* you can not be using iOS 6 SDK and even if you are able to fix your issue your app will be rejected for not supporting the 4" iOS device, which require you to use iOS 6 SDK.

Comment: Holly Molly dude, you are still using xcode 3.2. And they actually reviewed your app? Lucky you

Comment: so what should I do ? is the issue which I am facing is for the same reason?

Comment: @abhishekkeshari are you still having any issues with icons in your Xcode projects?

Answer (score 0):

Are [these guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW1) meet for your icon?

Comment: the image size which i am providing is 57x57 itself,but during submitting the app the following error is displayed